# Pass Play Framework parameter to javascript

Tags: javascript, playframework, playframework-2.0

I'm trying to pass a parameter coming from my controller to a javascript script so I can edit the data. But the javascript isn’t accepting my parameter.

Here is the code:

```
@for(status <- lista){
<tr>
<td>@status.getDescricao()</td>
<td><a href="javascript:;" onclick="enviar('formAltStatus/@status.getCodStatus()')"><img src="@routes.Assets.at("img/edit.png")" alt="" title="Editar"/></a>
                    <a href="@routes.StatusController.removerStatus(status.getCodStatus())"><img src="@routes.Assets.at("img/erase.png")" alt="" title="Remover"/></a>
</td>
</tr>
            }
```

The @status.getCodStatus() is my ID.

The route:

```
GET     /formAltStatus/:id              controllers.StatusController.formAltStatus(id:Long)
```

The javascript:

```
function enviar(a){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/"+a,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        dataType: "html",
        async:true,
        success: function(html){        
            $("#nova").html("");
            $("#nova").html(html);
            $("#logo").show();
        }
    });
}
```

Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HTML5 data attributes](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/htmlcss-tutorials/all-you-need-to-know-about-the-html5-data-attribute/) are designed for this situation where you have to pass server-side data to client-side functions. I think the best-practice solution is to add a data attribute to your anchor tag, and then retrieve the attribute value in Javascript.

```
<a ... data-status="@status.getCodStatus" data-param2="@param2">
```

This code then illustrates what the Javascript might look like. I don’t have much Javascript expertise so I’ve written a solution that uses JQuery. You will have to modify my suggestion if you're not using JQuery and are just using pure Javascript.

HTML:

```
<!-- Simple illustration of how to pass server-side data to a JS function -->
<a href="no-javascript.html" class="edit-link" data-status="@status.getCodStatus" data-param2="@param2">
    Hyperlink body goes here
</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.edit-link').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   statusCode = $(this).data('status', 'param2');
   alert(statusCode);
 });
```

[Live example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J8VRe/).

Answer (score 0):

Similiar situation.  Wanted to set the template parameter as an angular scope variable.  I passed the Json version of my model object and set it using ng-init.

**Server Side**

```
return ok(views.html.database.admin.chargeGroups.render(Json.toJson(commodity)));
```

**Front End**

```
@(commodity: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode)
@main("Charge Groups") {
<div ng-controller="ChargeGroupsController" ng-init="commodity = @commodity">
```